# ionic installation issue - windows7

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

while installing ionic using

```
npm install -g ionic
```

the following error shows

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>   "ionic"npm ERR! node v4.6.0npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9npm ERR! Invalid name:
>   "@ionic/app-generators"npm ERR!npm ERR! If you need help, you may
>   report this error at:npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issuesnpm ERR! Please include the
>   following file with any support request:npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\db2admin.user-PC.000\npm-debug.log

Comment: is this the full error log?

Comment: @suraj : yes. while installing this error shows .

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"npm ERR! node v4.6.0npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9npm ERR! Invalid name: "@ionic/app-generators"npm ERR!npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:npm ERR!     C:\Users\db2admin.user-PC.000\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your npm(v2.15.9) and node(v4.6.0) version are old -

Update npm with:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Then try to install ionic with

```
npm install -g ionic
```